# Submenu is not working for multiple items in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have submenu that is working for only when there is single item `li` tag but if I increase the number of `li` tags then stops working:

**My Code:-**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = (props) => {
  const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
        <ul className="submenu">
        <li>
          <Link to="/">
            <div
              onClick={() => setSubMenuOpen(!subMenuOpen)}
            >
              <span>test</span>
            </div>
          </Link>

          <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen ? "is-open" : ""}`}>
            <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
            <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
            <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">
            <div
              onClick={() => setSubMenuOpen(!subMenuOpen)}
            >
              <span>test</span>
            </div>
          </Link>

          <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen ? "is-open" : ""}`}>
            <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
            <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
            <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>

 </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```css
.sub-menu { display: none;}
.sub-menu.is-open { display:block;}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: May add your app.js file?

Comment: there is nothing in app.js

Comment: Do you wrap `Home.js` in `<Router>` ?

Comment: yes @Danial....

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'its not working fine' (or as I edited it to 'stops working' )? I see you have an answer, but it would be good for future question-searchers if you could clarify your original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have multiple submenus, you need to keep track of which one is open, and you can't do that with a single bool value.

If you will have only 1 level of child menu items, and at most one of them can be open, you can use a number: **`-1`** -> no subitem is open, **`0`** -> the first item is open, etc. like this:

- `const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(-1);`
- 1st div: `<div onClick={() => setSubMenuOpen(0)}>`
- 2nd div: `<div onClick={() => setSubMenuOpen(1)}>`
  *(etc)*
- 1st ul: `` <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen === 0 ? "is-open" : ""}`}> ``
- 2nd ul: `` <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen === 1 ? "is-open" : ""}`}> ``
  *(etc)*
- you probably also need to provision something that **clears** the menu, so clicking outside of the menu would run `setSubMenuOpen(-1)`.

To get toggling behaviour, you can use a helper function like this:

- helper function: `const toggleMenu = (x) => setSubMenuOpen(subMenuOpen === x ? -1 : x)`
- 1st div: `<div onClick={() => toggleMenu(0)}>`
- 2nd div: `<div onClick={() => toggleMenu(1)}>`

---

If you plan to have multiple levels of menu items, then a **tree-like data structure** will be more suitable, perhaps to both define the menu and to keep track of the open (*sub*)(sub)(***sub***)item.

Comment: This is working but I have to do this with toggle

Answer (score 0):

try using "className" instead of "class"
JSX seems to be right
I think you have a problem in css

Comment: changes class to className but nothing happened!